# Почему не работает автообновление browser-sync

Tags: javascript, gulp

Почему не работает автообновление? Зацикливается обновление `minCSS`

```js
gulp.task('minCSS', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/css/main.css')
    .pipe(minCSS())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

gulp.task('minJS', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/js/main.js')
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})


gulp.task('serve', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "app/"
    })

    gulp.watch("app/css/*.css", gulp.series('minCSS'))
    gulp.watch("app/js/*.js", gulp.series('minJS'))
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload)

})

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('serve'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Починил.
Изменил на

```js
    browserSync.watch("app/css/*.css", gulp.series('minCSS')).on('change', browserSync.reload)
    browserSync.watch("app/js/*.js", gulp.series('minJS')).on('change', browserSync.reload)
    browserSync.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload)
```